# Migrate Gitlab 8.0.3 to docker Gitlab 9.4.3 with data retore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, gitlab

We use Gitlab CE version 8.0.3 in our production environment. We installed it in a Centos7 virtual machine using an omnibus package.

We want to update it by passing it to the latest version of gitlab (version 9.4.3) and restore the data from the 8.0.3 version.

At the same time we want to install the new gitlab on a docker container hosted in a virtual machine other than the one on which the production gitlab is installed.

The problem facing us is:

How do I migrate with minimal downtime? Is it possible to switch directly from version 8.0.3 to version 9.4.3? How can we restore application data (projects, users, groups, etc.) in our new gitlab with a higher version?

**We tried to backup the data from our gitlab which runs in production and restore them in a containerized gitlab 9.4.3 using gitlab-rake, but we have an error message saying that it is impossible to restore 8.0.3 data In a 9.4.3 gitlab.**

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you should not migrate to a higher version at the same time and move to docker as well.

So you should upgrade to same version on docker or the least available version on docker. Then once you upgrade to 8.X on docker. Upgrade to last 8.X version or try an Upgrade directly to 9.X version

I had done a migration from 6.X to 8.X and it had lot of issues mostly because of migration. But migrating 8.X normal to 8.X docker should not be too much of an issue. You can try that and post individual issues that crop up in your question.

PS: I wrote an article on 6.X to 8.X migration [here](http://tarunlalwani.com/post/migrating-gitlab-6-mysql-to-latest-gitlab/). If you get stuck then it might help